# QGIS 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

Recently I was learning how to set up qgis server.

So here's the trouble I've encountered so far:

1. I was using OSGEO Live 5 Distribution ISO' Installed in dual boot mode with windows 7
2. I got the GetCapabilities work after fresh install.
   the response was as indicate in qgis server manual, the XML info about layer etc
3. After I execute update software system, then I tried to do the GetCapabilities returned 500 Internal Server Error.

I didn't do any change in the qgis system which was worked fine before software update.

What should I do to tackle this error

I'm very new to linux or foss, it just my work project have positioned me to like it or not to learn linux and foss.

so I followed up advice I open the error.log have information such as following:

```
[Sat Dec 24 22:33:54 2011] [error] mod_fcgid: process /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi(1862) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 6 
[Sat Dec 24 22:33:59 2011] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_fcgid: error reading data, FastCGI server closed connection 
[Sat Dec 24 22:33:59 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi 
[Sat Dec 24 22:34:05 2011] [error] mod_fcgid: process /usr/lib/cgi-bin/bik/qgis_mapserv.fcgi(1864) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 6 
[Sat Dec 24 22:35:10 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

what the information state and a follow up action to take to troubleshoot the error.

I also attached a link to the error.log file http://www.mediafire.com/?3zeuz48eeu8g8v1

Comment: Start by looking at the logs. They usually are stored in /var/log. That should give you more information as to what is not working and hopefully provide pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem recently. Not saying that this is best solution but it worked for me.

For me getcapabilities at http://domain.com/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities would give internal server error and same errors as you in apache2 log.

I created a directory in cgi-bin call map and symlinked qgis_mapserver.fcgi and map.qgs and with following link getcapabilities works as does the map server.

http://domain.com/cgi-bin/map/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even 6 years after, so here is the solution which worked for me.
QGIS-Server needs a virtualframebuffer running, so installing and running xvfb helps.
The steps are described here :
https://www.itopen.it/qgis-server-setup-notes/
(and then start the server with "/etc/init.d/xvfb start").